# How to extract sensitive output variables in terraform?

Tags: terraform, secret-key

I have a terraform config which creates an AWS IAM user with an access key, and I assign both id and secret to output variables:

```
...

resource "aws_iam_access_key" "brand_new_user" {
  user = aws_iam_user.brand_new_user.name
}

output "brand_new_user_id" {
  value = aws_iam_access_key.brand_new_user.id
}

output "brand_new_user_secret" {
  value     = aws_iam_access_key.brand_new_user.encrypted_secret
  sensitive = true
}
```

Here `brand_new_user_secret` is declared as sensitive, so `terraform output` obviously does not print it.

Is there any way to get its output value without parsing the whole state file?
Trying to access it directly (`terraform output brand_new_user_secret`) does not work (results in an error "The output variable requested could not be found in the state file...").

Terraform version: 0.12.18

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I had some hopes to avoid it, but so far I did not find a better way than parse terraform state:

```
terraform state pull | jq '.resources[] | select(.type == "aws_iam_access_key") | .instances[0].attributes'
```

which would result in a structure similar to:

```
{
  "encrypted_secret": null,
  "id": "....",
  "key_fingerprint": null,
  "pgp_key": null,
  "secret": "....",
  "ses_smtp_password": "....",
  "ses_smtp_password_v4": null,
  "status": "Active",
  "user": "...."
}
```

Comment: this means that Terraform state is sensitive, it stores secrets too.. is that safe?

Answer (score 22):

To see the sensitive value interactively, i.e. for the purposes of analyzing/debugging the state, you can use the Terraform's [console command](https://www.terraform.io/docs/cli/commands/console.html) and [nonsensitive()](https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/functions/nonsensitive.html) function:

```
$ terraform console

> nonsensitive(aws_iam_access_key.brand_new_user.encrypted_secret)
```

You may need to use other functions to decode/manipulate the value before printing it.

Answer (score 8):

The *output* command does print a sensitive output if a single output is specified.  This is using Terraform v1.1.7 and 0.14.8

```
terraform output brand_new_user_secret
```

The response I get when not specifying an attribute name is:

```
brand_new_user_secret = (sensitive)
```

whereas the question said this produced an error, so the behaviour may have changed since 0.12.

See https://www.terraform.io/cli/commands/output

Answer (score 6):

I'm using a hacky workaround here like this...

```
resource "aws_iam_access_key" "brand_new_user" {
  user = aws_iam_user.brand_new_user.name
}

output "brand_new_user_id" {
  value = aws_iam_access_key.brand_new_user.id
}

data "template_file" "secret" {
  template = aws_iam_access_key.brand_new_user.encrypted_secret
}

output "brand_new_user_secret" {
  value     = data.template_file.secret.rendered
}
```

Comment: Thank you, @mark! I thought about it, but I did not want to go this route as it's not secure: plain output is often saved and stored in a non-secured location - for example in config folder that is used by different modules of your system (e.g. if you don't want to hardcode the instance ID's in your code). In contrast the state should be always treated as sensitive.

Comment: I wanted to pass the output from one module as template string into another module (this finally would get written into a file on remote server). Not the best of practices, but needed for the time being. Thus, I followed your trick.

Answer (score 5):

I think the recommended way to do this with modern Terraform (v1.1+) is to use `terraform output -json [<name>]`. The `-json` switch bypasses Terraform's sensitive value masking.

For example, with Terraform 1.2.7, to list and unmask all outputs:

```
$ terraform output -json
{
  "app_database_password": {
    "sensitive": true,
    "type": "string",
    "value": "..."
  }
}
```

Or, if you just want a single output's value without needing to parse JSON (n.b. still seems to be enclosed in quotes):

```
$ terraform output -json app_database_password
"..."
```

Answer (score 3):

I haven't tried it, but the docs seem to suggest that if you want to output `encrypted_secret` you must supply a `pgp_key` to the `aws_iam_access_key` resource:

> - pgp_key - (Optional) Either a base-64 encoded PGP public key, or a keybase username in the form keybase:some_person_that_exists, for use in the encrypted_secret output attribute.
> - encrypted_secret - The encrypted secret, base64 encoded, if pgp_key was specified. ~> NOTE: The encrypted secret may be decrypted using the command line, for example: terraform output encrypted_secret | base64 --decode | keybase pgp decrypt.

https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/r/iam_access_key.html