# Create a key pair and download the .pem file with Terraform (AWS)

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, terraform, private-key, key-pair

I could create the key pair `myKey` to `AWS` with `Terraform`.

```
resource "tls_private_key" "pk" {
  algorithm = "RSA"
  rsa_bits  = 4096
}

resource "aws_key_pair" "kp" {
  key_name   = "myKey"       # Create a "myKey" to AWS!!
  public_key = tls_private_key.pk.public_key_openssh
}
```

AWS:

[image]

But I couldn't download the `myKey.pem` file. Is it possible to download the `myKey.pem` file with `Terraform` like below?

[image]

Answer (score 17, accepted):

### Feb, 2022 Update:

No, it's not possible to download the `myKey.pem` file with `Terraform`. Instead, we can create the `myKey.pem` file which has the same `private key` as the key pair `myKey` on `AWS`. So the created `myKey` and `myKey.pem` file by `Terraform` are the same as those which we manually create and download on `AWS`. This is the code below. (I used Terraform v0.15.4)

```
resource "tls_private_key" "pk" {
  algorithm = "RSA"
  rsa_bits  = 4096
}

resource "aws_key_pair" "kp" {
  key_name   = "myKey"       # Create a "myKey" to AWS!!
  public_key = tls_private_key.pk.public_key_openssh

  provisioner "local-exec" { # Create a "myKey.pem" to your computer!!
    command = "echo '${tls_private_key.pk.private_key_pem}' > ./myKey.pem"
  }
}
```

Don't forget to make `myKey.pem` file only readable by you running the code below before ssh to your ec2 instance.

```
chmod 400 myKey.pem
```

Otherwise the error below occurs.

```
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
@         WARNING: UNPROTECTED PRIVATE KEY FILE!          @
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
Permissions 0664 for 'myKey.pem' are too open.
It is required that your private key files are NOT accessible by others.
This private key will be ignored.
Load key "myKey.pem": bad permissions
ubuntu@35.72.30.251: Permission denied (publickey).
```

Answer (score 8):

Terraform resource `tls_private_key` has attributes that can be exported. [This](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/tls/latest/docs/resources/private_key#attributes-reference) is the list.

The way you would download `myKey.pem` using Terraform would be by exporting the attribute `private_key_pem` to a local file.

So in your case, it would be:

```
resource "tls_private_key" "pk" {
  algorithm = "RSA"
  rsa_bits  = 4096
}

resource "aws_key_pair" "kp" {
  key_name   = "myKey"       # Create a "myKey" to AWS!!
  public_key = tls_private_key.pk.public_key_openssh
}

resource "local_file" "ssh_key" {
  filename = "${aws_key_pair.kp.key_name}.pem"
  content = tls_private_key.pk.private_key_pem
}
```

**Note**:

1. You can't export the content of attribute `private_key_pem` using either of resources `tls_private_key` and `local_file`. If you *really* wan't to, [here's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59473690/how-to-extract-sensitive-output-variables-in-terraform) how.
2. The file `myKey.pem` is generated by Terraform with permissions `755`. You would need to change this to `400`

Comment: You could add the file permission as well to terraform
resource "local_file" "ssh_key" {
  ...
  file_permission = "0400"
}

Comment: this version is dope because it works on windows

Comment: Although the other answer works ... this should be flagged as the correct answer as the implementation is more reusable and TF way of solving the problem.

Comment: Careful when using this for production: the private key will be stored [plainly](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/tls/latest/docs/resources/private_key) in Terraform state, which may lead to inadvertently leaking it.